# Python list has none type elements even though filled with dataframe elements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, nonetype

I initialize a list of length n using `df_list = [None] * n`. Then I have a for loop where I fill each element of `df_list` with a dataframe. Then, when I concat all these dataframes together using `df = pd.concat(df_list, axis=0)` I end up with fewer rows than expected, and upon further inspection I find that some elements of `df_list` are `None` type while others are dataframes. This is strange to me because in my for loop, I print the type of each value before filling it into `df_list` and they are all dataframes of the desired shape and columns as well.

Wondering how, after running the loop, I can have `None` values in `df_list` when each value I filled in is a dataframe and not `None`.

Any help here is appreciated - quite puzzled by this!

Comment: is there a reproducable example you can post?

Comment: it could be that you are mixing dataframe types, but I can't tell for sure without looking at it. have a look at `df.astype('int')` and try setting it to the same thing for every one of your dfs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you even need to initialize the list with None values. Just create empty list and append your dataframes to it.

Comment: I just tried this and it fixed my issue - thank you! However, appending increases the run time as compared to filling in the empty list. I also don't understand why this fixed the issue and my original approach didn't work?

Comment: @emillyrock you need to provide a [mcve]. Pre-allocating a `list` in python generally is not significantly faster than growing a list with `.append`